# Where to find older versions of QT (e.g. QT 4.6)?

Tags: qt

I'v scoured the internet but to no avail. Can anyone help me find the older releases of QT ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE 20150622:**

The webpage (http://www.qt-project.org) page has moved to http://www.qt.io. The download page is now at http://download.qt.io/archive/, and the archive page is now at http://download.qt.io/archive/.

**UPDATE 20131128:**

[In March 2011, Nokia sold the commercial licensing part of Qt to Digia creating Qt Commercial.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) In the process, the downloads ***for the open-source packages*** moved to http://download.qt-project.org/, with the archives now being at http://download.qt-project.org/archive/. ***Commercial releases*** are distributed via the [Digia Customer Portal](http://qt.digia.com/Log-in-Customer-Portal/) and a separate distribution system.

The old ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/ does not contain relevant content anymore.

**UPDATE END**

for the sdk, the archives are at

ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/pub/qtsdk/

`*-2010.04*` seems to be Qt 4.6.3, `*-2010.05*` Qt 4.7. for details of the corresponding Qt versions, google the full file name, eg. http://www.google.com/search?q=%22qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.05.exe%22, or order the ftp directoy listing by "last modified" and correlate with Qt version release dates.

if you only need the libraries, go to

ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/pub/qt/source/

(which seems to be exactly the same as ftp://ftp.trolltech.com/qt/source/)

Answer (score 9):

Since Qt is in part maintained by the Qt Project, you can find all sources of all releases in their archive:

> http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/

For Qt 4.6, this means:

> http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.6/

The current releases reside under another directory:

> http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/

Answer (score 4):

The links provided by ax are dead now, and I found some SDK (with qt libraries 4.7, 4.6, 4.5) at

ftp://ftp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/pub/Linux/Qt/QT/qtsdk/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? ftp://ftp.trolltech.com/qt/source/

Comment: I found that earlier, but didn't trust it. Is it credible?

Comment: Might be outdated, but it's the official website, isn't it?  See: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolltech#History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolltech#History)

Answer (score 0):

As September 2014:
http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/

It will change now that Qt has moved to http://qt.io

Answer (score 0):

This (official) page links to specific releases—which could be found through the URLs in some of the other answers—but I think the format of this page is a bit easier to navigate:

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Versions

(The download links all point to files hosted at http://download.qt.io/archive/ or ftp://ftp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/pub/Linux/Qt/QT/qtsdk/.)

Answer (score -1):

On the download section of their site, then other releases.

http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/
Goes all the way back to version 1.